# What exactly is the difficulty in giving a precise definition to dependent type theories?

Tags: type-theory

In this talk by fields Medalist Vladmir Voevodosky on "The meta theory of dependent type theories" dated at Feb 27, 2017, the following is said:

> I start with a few words about the title. Neither of the two concepts that it is composed of - "a meta-theory" and "dependent type theories" has a precise mathematical definition. ..

Why was there no precise theory? What is the difficulty in making it precise?